# Solve this equation $\frac{1}{x+\sqrt{x^2-1}}=\frac{1}{4x}+\frac{3x}{2x^2+2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Solve this equation
>   $$\frac{1}{x+\sqrt{x^2-1}}=\frac{1}{4x}+\frac{3x}{2x^2+2}$$

This equation has solutions $x=\pm 1$ but I cannot find a solution.
Do you think using an inequality will is the way forward?

Comment: I don't know if it is actually helpful here, but it may be of use that $$\frac{1}{x+\sqrt{x^2-1}}=x-\sqrt{x^2-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{x+\sqrt{x^2-1}}=x-\sqrt{x^2-1}=\frac{7x^2+1}{4x^3+4x}$$

$$\sqrt{x^2-1}=\frac{4x^4-3x^2-1}{4x^3+4x}=\frac{(4x^2+1)\cdot(x-1)\cdot(x+1)}{4x\cdot(x^2+1)}$$

$$\sqrt{x^2-1}\geq0,\space so\space\space x \in [-1,0] \cup \{1\}$$

$$x^2-1=(x-1)\cdot(x+1)=\frac{(4x^2+1)^2\cdot(x-1)^2\cdot(x+1)^2}{16x^2\cdot(x^2+1)^2}$$

$$(x-1)\cdot(x+1)\cdot(\frac{(4x^2+1)^2\cdot(x-1)\cdot(x+1)}{16x^2\cdot(x^2+1)^2}-1)=0$$

$$\rightarrow x \in \{-1,1\}$$

Answer (score 0):

LHS part is equal to $x - \sqrt{x^2-1}$ and RHS is $\frac{1+ 7x^2}{4x^3 +4x}$. Thus,

$$ x - \sqrt{x^2-1} =  \frac{1+ 7x^2}{4x^3 +4x} \Rightarrow x^2 -1 = \left(\frac{1+7x^2}{4x^3 +4x} -x \right)^2 \Rightarrow (x^2-1)(4x^3+4x)^2 = (-4x^4 +3x^2+1)^2 \Rightarrow 40x^6 -17x^4 -22x^2 -1 = 0.$$ I think you can solve now.